# How to populate a 'map' table from words of a text?

Tags: mysql, insert, subquery

Having the database structure that follows:

```
CREATE TABLE articles
(
article_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
article text,
PRIMARY KEY(article_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE words
(
word_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
word varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY(word_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE word_map
(
article_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
word_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(article_id) REFERENCES articles(article_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY(word_id) REFERENCES words(word_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
PRIMARY KEY(article_id, word_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

How can I split the `text` column in the `article` table to find the words which exist in the `words` table and, then, `INSERT` the words into `word_map`?

Now I am doing this in PHP by splitting the `text` into `words`, then, finding `word_id` for each word, and then, `INSERT INTO word_map (article_id, word_id)`.

Comment: Have a look at [Full text search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html) functions for MySql.

Comment: @McNets I have `FULLTEXT` index for the search purpose, but how to plan a subquery to insert the map?

Comment: If you have `FULLTEXT`, you don't need the other two tables.  See the docs on how to use `MATCH ... AGAINST ...`

Comment: @RickJames why not? two other tables can have other useful columns such as various counts, status, tracking, etc. `FULLTEXT` is good for searching.

Comment: For key-value, you do not need a many:many mapping table.